# Unable to get the id of an element

Tags: javascript

The JSFiddle below is a simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish.
My code generates a. anchor element that is passed to a `div`.
I'd like it to return its id when double clicked but get an `undefined` instead.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6kpttcxL/)

```
function abc() {
    var myString = "<a onclick='bcd(this);' id='1'>krokodil</a>";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myString;
}

function bcd(e) {
        alert(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are alerting the id of `this`, which is not equal to `e` in the scope of the function. Change the function to

```js
function abc() {
    var myString = "<a onclick='bcd(this);' id='1'>krokodil</a>";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myString;
}

function bcd(e) {
        alert(e.id);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="abc()">ADD</button>
<div id="output">kikker</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of `this` depends on how you call the function.

Since you are calling `bcd` without an explicitly object (`foo.bcd()`) and are not in strict mode, the value will be equal to `window` (in a browser).

You are reading the id of the window, not the element.

Look at the `e` variable instead of `this` (since you pass it the element from the click event handler).

Answer (score 3):

The parameter you are passing to the `alert` function is referenced as `e`, but you then attempt to alert `this.id`. `this` refers to the function calling the expression. Try this:

```
function abc() {
    var myString = "<a onclick='bcd(this.id);' id='1'>krokodil</a>";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myString;
}

function bcd(e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

Note that you also need to update the `onclick()` event to include the `id` property

Answer (score 1):

change

> alert(this.id); to 
>    alert(e)